# Using a dynamic value in service constructor

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, angularfire2

I have a service that generates the observables for each type of content in my app. In this observable, I want to be able to use the firebase user ID to generate a dynamic path (`collectionPath`). I am able to retrieve the user ID in my different modules and components, but here I need to pass it inside the constructor, and everything I have tried returns `undefined`. How can I use that dynamic value inside the constructor to have dynamic paths for my firebase queries?

EDIT: I need to set `userId` to the user ID of the currently loggedIn user, when declaring it. If I can do that, the rest will work fine. If not possible, to set it to a value passed from the parent component using the service.

I have tried passing the value from the component where the service is used to the service value like this `this.collectionService.userId = [the user ID from a subscribe]`. I console log every step, and the value I am passing is correct but reads as undefined as used inside the service constructor.

I have tried retrieving the value inside the service, but haven't been able to pass it to the paths defined in the constructor. I log the value when getting it to the service through a method and works, but it isn't used in building the path.

I have also tried setting the userId with an async function and await. Still get undefined.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CategoryINTF } from 'src/app/interfaces/components/handlers/category.interface';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CollectionsService {

private patientsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<CategoryINTF>;
private patients: Observable<CategoryINTF[]>;

private user: object;
public userId: string;
private albumId: string;
private collectionPath = 'users/' + this.userId;

  constructor(
    db: AngularFirestore,
    authInfo: AngularFireAuth
    ) {

    // OBSERVABLES
    // PATIENTS
    this.patientsCollection = db.collection<CategoryINTF>(this.collectionPath + '/patients'); // <-- THE PATH I NEED TO SET
    this.patients = this.patientsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
      actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        });
      }
    ));
  }

  async setPatient(Uid: string, id: string, catLabel: string) {
    this.userId = Uid;
    await this.userId;
    console.log("setPatient fired!!!");
    console.log("userId: " + this.userId); //correct
    console.log("collectionPath: " + this.collectionPath);//undefined
    return this.patientsCollection.doc(id).set({ 
    'label': catLabel,
    'id': id }); 
  }

  testUserID(id: string) {
    this.userId = id;
    console.log("GOT IT???: " + this.userId); // <-- logs correctly
  }

}
```

When creating a new patient doc, it should use the userId value to create a dynamic path. Currently that user always returns undefined in the path, so the patient docs are created under a user wih id 'undefined' in firebase. The write operation is working, just not where it should.

I am guessing there is something about how the constructor works that I am ignoring... help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't know if it is the ideal answer, but it worked!

Save the userId using `localStorage` so that it can be retrieved from anywhere whileusing the app. [Here is the link to the solution I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748714/grabbing-the-current-user-in-angularfireauth).

The main obstacle is that the uid is usually served through an observable. By storing the value in localStorage, one can access it as a string app-wide, making the setup of all the other observables much easier and reducing many lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As you're injecting `afauth` into the constructor, if you set this as `private` then you could still access from other methods and pull the current user info via `this.authInfo.auth.currentUser`

You're also defining `collectionPath` before `userId` is defined so `userId` will be undefined.

As for `await this.userId`, as `userId` is a variable, there is nothing to wait for so you can safely remove this (only await for asynchronous code).

Finally, instead of concatenating all your console logs, you might find it easier to comma-separate or use inline templates, i.e.:

```
console.log('userId', this.userId)
```

or

```
console.log(`userId: ${this.userId}`)
```